# Using %>% operator from dplyr without loading dplyr in R

Tags: r, operators, dplyr

I'm currently building a package and I was wondering if there was a way to call the `%>%` operator from dplyr without actually attaching the dplyr package. For example, with any function that is being exported from a package, you can call it with the double colon (`::`). So if I wanted to use the `group_by` function without attaching dplyr, I would enter `dplyr::group_by`. Is there something similar for operators?

Comment: I think the `%>%` function is actually imported from 'pkg:magrittr'. You would need to quote or backtick the `%>%`

Comment: You will have to use `magrittr::\`%>%\``

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can refer to any object with non-standard name by enclosing in backticks.  This means you can do this:

```
`%>%` <- magrittr::`%>%`
```

This will define the `%>%` operator in your current environment. For example:

```
iris %>% head

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way would be to load the `magrittr` package, which only does piping, and is the original source of `%>%`. If you don't want to load any packages, you can still use `%>%`, but not in any really useful way (unless you define it in your environment as Andrie suggests). Using it with `::` would go like this:

```
# standard use
mtcars %>% summary()
# :: use
magrittr::"%>%"(mtcars, summary())
```

You really lose any advantage of readability/not nesting with this method.

Since you say you're building a package, you should put `magrittr` in Imports, or even just us importsFrom and grab the `"%>%"` function. [See here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 'dplyr' installed but not loaded you can get a result with:

```
 dplyr::`%>%`   # Note the backticks, although quotes work as well.
```

That displays the code but at the bottom you will see that its environment is actually the NAMESPACE of 'magritter' which 'dplyr' imports. As the two other knowledgeable respondents point out there are a couple of ways to use it as a function although it cannot just be interposed between a `lhs` and a `rhs` argument unless you make a local copy that has the flanking "%"'s or call it with the functional parentheses. The R parser won't allow:

```
>  mtcars dplyr::"%>%" summary()
Error: unexpected symbol in " mtcars dplyr"
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a clash between the pipe notation as implemented in dplyr and the double colon notation. I didn't find anything about it in the documentation.

```
## This works:
base::mean(1:10)

## This doesn't:
1:10 %>% base::mean

## It works after parenthesizing though:
1:10 %>% (base::mean)
```

It could be made a bit more prominent in the docs.
This issue was moved by romainfrancois from tidyverse/dplyr#3958.

source : https://github.com/tidyverse/magrittr/issues/183